# Custom TabBar in top

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, tabbar

Custom TabBar:

[image: Custom TabBar]

I'm a newbie in using Xcode or swift, I want to make a custom TabBar like the picture above, then how to put the tab above the view like the picture above? I've made it using storyboard but I'm still confused moving the tab above the view? Is this possible?

TabBar from StoryBoard:

[image: TabBar from StoryBoard]

Comment: You may use custom controls to achieve this.

Comment: @RJ168 Thx done with XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to this world, well there's no such native control in iOS kit by which you can get a top tab bar, but lucikly there is a 3rd party library which will fulfill your design needs

https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Here's it is, all you need is to add it into your project using cocoapods after that follow its demo project and you will have a top tab bar in your project.
:)